# List Item Responsive Issue in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I would like to do responsive list item. How can I set the list items side by side. It's been always showing one under the other.
Here is my code;

```
    <l:Grid
defaultSpan="L6 M6 S12"
class="sapUiNoMargin sapUiNoContentPadding"
hSpacing="5"
vSpacing="5">
<l:content>
    <List>
        <items>
            <!--TodoItem-->
            <CustomListItem type="Active" press="handlePanel3" class="todoListItemContainer">
                <Panel class="todoListItem">
                    <!--Content-->
                </Panel>
            </CustomListItem>

            <!--PlanItem and ActivityItem-->
            <CustomListItem type="Active" press="handlePanel3" class="todoListItemContainer">
                <Panel class="todoListItem">
                    <!--Content-->
                </Panel>
            </CustomListItem>

        </items>
    </List>
</l:content>
```

Here is the output image;
How can I put these items side by side. Grid’s responsive layout properties is L6 M6 S12 but it’s not working. Where I am doing a mistake ? Thanks for your suggestions.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Within the List the Grid layout will not apply, as the layout applies only on the immediate child controls. You can set the list items side by side in two ways

1. Remove the List & place the CustomListItem directly in the Grid control.

   ```
                   <!--PlanItem and ActivityItem-->
                   <CustomListItem type="Active" press="handlePanel3" class="todoListItemContainer">
                       <Panel class="todoListItem">
                           <!--Content-->
                       </Panel>
                   </CustomListItem>

       </l:content>
   </l:Grid>
   ```
2. Use 2 Lists inside the Grid (As suggested by [Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1083921/marc))

   ```
   <l:Grid
       defaultSpan="L6 M6 S12"
       class="sapUiNoMargin sapUiNoContentPadding"
       hSpacing="5"
       vSpacing="5">
       <l:content>
           <List>
               <items>
                   <!--TodoItem-->
                   <CustomListItem type="Active" press="handlePanel3" class="todoListItemContainer">
                       <Panel class="todoListItem">
                           <!--Content-->

                       </Panel>
                   </CustomListItem>
               </items>
           </List>
           <List>
               <items>
                   <!--PlanItem and ActivityItem-->
                   <CustomListItem type="Active" press="handlePanel3" class="todoListItemContainer">
                       <Panel class="todoListItem">
                           <!--Content-->

                       </Panel>
                   </CustomListItem>
               </items>
           </List>
       </l:content>
   </l:Grid>
   ```